# MINIO: GetVersions of the object

Tags: version, minio

I'm a beginner in MinIO and I want to know Is there any way to get all versions of object? I ony have the name of the object, and I want to know what version it has?
Please help

EDIT: I use minio-dotnet-master

Comment: Using command line or api if api,which sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Using Minio Client : [mc client](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide.html)

`mc ls --versions s3/mybucket/object`

Most minio sdks support retrieving versions.

e.g `list_objects` in [mino-py](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html) with `include_version = True`